# Bucketing algorithm in Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

Bitcoin core states that an entry can be part of maximum 8 buckets. I don't understand how an entry can map to 8 buckets when the data in the entry is the same.

```
uint64_t hash1 = (CHashWriter(SER_GETHASH, 0) << nKey << GetGroup(asmap) << vchSourceGroupKey).GetCheapHash();

uint64_t hash2 = (CHashWriter(SER_GETHASH, 0) << nKey << vchSourceGroupKey << (hash1 % ADDRMAN_NEW_BUCKETS_PER_SOURCE_GROUP)).GetCheapHash();

return hash2 % ADDRMAN_NEW_BUCKET_COUNT;
```

When the input is the same, how can it return 8 different values?

Answer (score 1):

That code is from `src\addrman.cpp`. The code's author has in the past [pointed out the associated comments](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=97297.0) in [`addrman.h`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/addrman.h#L91) starting around line 91

You should refer to the original source but I'll quote the relevant comments here

(https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

Stochastic address manager

Design goals:

- Keep the address tables in-memory, and asynchronously dump the entire table to peers.dat.
- Make sure no (localized) attacker can fill the entire table with his nodes/addresses.

To that end:

- Addresses are organized into buckets that can each store up to 64 entries.

  - Addresses to which our node has not successfully connected go into 1024 "new" buckets.

    - Based on the address range (/16 for IPv4) of the source of information, or if an asmap is provided,
      the AS it belongs to (for IPv4/IPv6), 64 buckets are selected at random.
    - The actual bucket is chosen from one of these, based on the range in which the address itself is located.
    - The position in the bucket is chosen based on the full address.
    - One single address can occur in up to 8 different buckets to increase selection chances for addresses that
      are seen frequently. The chance for increasing this multiplicity decreases exponentially.
    - When adding a new address to an occupied position of a bucket, it will not replace the existing entry
      unless that address is also stored in another bucket or it doesn't meet one of several quality criteria
      (see IsTerrible for exact criteria).
    - Addresses of nodes that are known to be accessible go into 256 "tried" buckets.

      - Each address range selects at random 8 of these buckets.
      - The actual bucket is chosen from one of these, based on the full address.
      - When adding a new good address to an occupied position of a bucket, a FEELER connection to the
        old address is attempted. The old entry is only replaced and moved back to the "new" buckets if this
        attempt was unsuccessful.
    - Bucket selection is based on cryptographic hashing, using a randomly-generated 256-bit key, which should not
      be observable by adversaries.
    - Several indexes are kept for high performance. Setting m_consistency_check_ratio with the -checkaddrman
      configuration option will introduce (expensive) consistency checks for the entire data structure.

> **I don't understand how an entry can map to 8 buckets when the data in the entry is the same.**

To me, the comments suggest that, for tried nodes, the address *range* (e.g. 99.0/16) selects eight buckets but the whole address (e.g. 99.0.0.55) selects one of those eight.

I've no idea if that helps, but I think it ought to, and if not, someone more knowledgable will probably provide a better answer.